# RegEx for extracting all characters between a special character and a word

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract all characters(usually multiple words including space) between a special character `>` and a word pattern `.myword`. in my pandas dataframe.

I have tried the following which only brings one word attached to `.myword`:

```
df['my_column'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'(\w+.myword)')
```

Some string examples:

```
str1 = 123abc >I want this1.myword #extract I want this1.myword
str2 =  123<>I want this2.myword<> #extract I want this2.myword
```

Comment: Generally `>(.*?)\.myword` or `(?<=>).+?(?=\.myword)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a simple dot `.` matches any character, so you want to escape it in your regex: `\.` Otherwise, the regex will also find a match in e.g.:
`123>Iwantthis!myword  # extracts Iwantthis!myword`

Second, you have to allow whitespace characters in the captured group: `\s`.

I guess this should do the job for you:
`r'([\w\s]+\.myword)'`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<$]+' <<EOF
123abc >I want this1.myword
123<>I want this2.myword<>
EOF

I want this1.myword
I want this2.myword
```

- `(?<=)` Positive Lookbehind
- `[^]` Negative character set

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regex, I would define a specific function to extract the substring:

#### Code

```
def substring(original_string):
    start = original_string.find(">")
    end = original_string.find(".myword")

    if (start > -1) and (end > -1):
        return original_string[start + 1:end]
    else:
        return None


df['my_column'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: substring(x))
```